# ksh: Not importing prompt settings from /etc/profile

Tags: linux, shell, ksh, prompt

I am using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 and I am facing an issue related with a user using `ksh`.

I have created a user as follows:

`testenv:$2y$10$vjUVUejLhMGoTn2CHPqmU.kFOR8qex9STqNqiaqVZ0H8XR4MH1dEi:50004:121:Test Environment:/home/testenv:/usr/bin/ksh`

Certain lines were appended to `/etc/profile` file in order to customize the shell prompt, which are as follows:

```
Cy="${Esc}[36m"  # start cyan
Re="${Esc}[31m"  # start red
Yl="${Esc}[33m"  # start bolding in yellow
Ba="${Esc}[0m"   # end everything

PS1="${Cy}`hostname` $Re$USER${Yl} ";PS1=$PS1'[${PWD##*/}]';PS1=$PS1'$Ba > '
```

No changes are made to `/etc/ksh.kshrc`.

When I log into the server as that particular user using `su - testenv`, I get following prompt:

```
h:w>
```

But, when I execute `source /etc/profile` after logging in, I get the expected results. I have also observed that, same configurations are working fine on SLES 10. What might be the issue here?

Comment: I can confirm that it works as expected on Debian. I'm guessing there's probably another file in the user's `$HOME` which is setting PS1. Look in `~/.profile`. Also check what `ENV` is set to when logging in as that user.

Comment: This looks like a setting for bash (`PS1='\h:\w>'` would display the host name and working directory). What is the entire content of `/etc/profile`? What dot files does the user have (`ls -lA ~`)?

Comment: @terdon `ENV` is set to `/home/testenv/.kshrc`, which is an empty file. And there is no `.profile` file.

Comment: @Gilles - Shall I paste the contents of `/etc/profile` here? Following are the dot files in user's home directory - `.bash_history`, `.cpan`, `.fonts.cache-2`, `.idlerc`, `.kshrc_history`,`.lesshst`, `.local`, `.mysql_history`, `.rnd`, `.sh_history`, `.ssh` , `.viminfo`.

Comment: @MandarShinde Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the prompt global setting defined in `/etc/profile` is overwritten by the prompt user setting in `~/.profile` ?

Comment: No such file `~/.profile` found. Did you mean `~/.bash_profile`? I have checked with `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`, but no such files were there.

Comment: Ksh uses `~/.profile` (if it exists) for user custom settings.